sudo apt-get update failed in Ubuntu 24.04
The output of sudo apt-get update command is:
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [344 B]
Reading package lists... Done  
          
E: The repository 'file:/cdrom noble Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Thank you for helping me to solve this problem My Ubuntu version is 24.04

This question is similar to: Repository does not have release file error for ubuntu 20.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Problem with sudo apt get update: The repository cdrom... does not have a Release file. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

the warning you are seeing is due to an attempt to update from a cd-rom repository that no longer has a valid release file.
to resolve this issue you have to edit /etc/apt/sources.list and remove or comment the cd-rom entry.
after this change update package lists again:
sudo apt-get update

this should resolve the issue, and you shouldn't see the warning about the cd-rom repository anymore.
